# Having trouble finding the no. of mappings for an unlabelled graph?

Tags: graph-theory

[image: Image from Bondy"s graph theory book]

Sorry if it looks like a trivial question but i am fairly novice in graph theory, I have included the image which tries to calculate the no. of distinct mappings for various  permutations of G intersecting with H to get F. The no. of instances of F for each of 4 graph examples for a particular G and H is given in the picture. **I am not able to wrap my head around how the third graph got 8 the one circled in red in image.** Also is the process of finding |G->H|F different for labelled graphs vs. unlabelled or should we assign labels if we even encounter unlabelled graphs.

Comment: That doesn't seem correct; in the case of $|G \to H|_F$ the four cases for $F$ should be the four spanning subgraphs of $H$, not the four spanning subgraphs of $G$ that are shown.

Comment: Yeah I guess so bcoz no permutation of G intersected with H will give us the third graph but if like you said it was a subgraph of H we would get 8 mappings like shown in the figure l.